# Is Ivanka Kushner really Donald Trump's daughter?

Tags: halacha

Is referring to Ivanka Kushner as a "daughter" of Donald Trump wrong from a Torah standpoint, being that Jewish tradition considers a convert to Judiasm as a newborn child with no relation to his or her biological parents?

Comment: Are you asking if using this term in this context is prohibited? What do you mean by "wrong"? I'm not sure what commandment it would violate

Comment: @MarkA. First, any clarifications to the question should be done in the question itself. Second, If your definitive statement "And that's wrong" is to be taken at face value, then there does not seem to be room for a question. Third, I again recommend that you demonstrate that Hazal actually said this, and in which context they said this, and then clarify which element of paternity you are asking about. To repeat my earlier point: paternity of not binary. It is associated with multiple characteristics, biological, social, legal, etc. Which are you asking about?

Comment: I think that this is answered here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59194/do-i-sit-shiva-after-my-parents-if-i-am-converted-to-judaism -- the answers point out a relationship of respect remaining because (it seems) even though there is a halachic status change, there is still a biological link.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48810/discussion-on-question-by-mark-a-is-ivanka-kushner-really-donald-trumps-daught).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it *may* be wrong to do so, at least under some circumstances.

*Shulchan Aruch*, *CM* 228  says "אם היה בן גרים לא יאמר לו זכור מעשי אבותיך", that one cannot remind a descendant of converts of his ancestors' acts. I have always assumed that this injunction is against reminding such a person that his ancestry didn't believe in God and follow the Torah's rules for gentiles (as indeed is true of the extremely vast majority of *gerim* and (I believe) of Ms. Trump). If that interpretation is correct, then mentioning (where Ms. Trump can read/hear it) that she's Mr. Trump's daughter would presumably violate that rule if one also mentions any of various acts or beliefs of Mr. Trump's (or of her own before conversion).

Comment: This seems to be deliberately missing the point of the OP. The Shulhan Arukh is referencing the halakha that one may not humiliate a convert in any way, including with embarrassing references to his or her background. This seems wholly irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @mevaqesh, irrespective of the asker's morivation, the question at hand is whether it's wrong to refer to her as his daughter. That's the question I answered. And, frankly, as noted in numerous comments on the question post, the motivation behind the question is very weak; especially in such a case, IMO, answering the question itself and ignoring its motivation is just fine.

Comment: It seems overwhelmingly clear from context that the question is how to regard her paternity, not whether it is permissible to insult her. || The quoted statement refers to insulting the behaviours of one's ancestors. It does not address referring to a convert in terms of his parents, and it certainly does not address who the convert is considered descended of.

Comment: @mevaqesh re "It does not address referring to a convert in terms of his parents" (because I think I addressed your other points in my previous comment): True, I extrapolated a little bit. That's why I wrote (and emphasized) "may be" in my answer.

Comment: Also onaas devarim would only come into play when talking to her, not about her. And I checked the shu'a. The language you quote is actually not there, even though that was the example in the gemara and tur.