# Mourning for a Noahide Father

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mourning-aveilus, noachide-laws

This question is different than others I've read regarding mourning a Non-Jewish parent.  I'm specifically interested in the case of a Noahide father and a Jewish mother who have divorced.  What I mean by Noahide is someone who professes belief in HaShem, but does not attend any non-Jewish religious services or engage in any conduct forbidden to a non-Jew by the Torah.  Going beyond this, the Jewish child was raised Jewish by the non-Jewish father, and through the father's active support eventual became religiously observant.  What would be the proper way to mourn such a parent?

Comment: I've read that Rav Ovadia Yosef dealt with something similar in Yehaveh Da’at 6:60, but don't have access to it.

Comment: https://library.yctorah.org/2018/01/saying-kaddish-for-a-non-jewish-parent/

Comment: Why would this be different than the question you claim it is different from?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's more specific.  They're divorced so there is no issue of being in a forbidden relationship.  There is no issue of the father maybe being an idolater, and no issue of conversion.

Comment: Sure, but is there any reason to think any of those are relevant differences? I wasn't saying it was literally the same words as the other question.

Comment: related: [Sitting shiva for non-Jewish relatives?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28159/11501)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether a Jewish son should mourn his righteous non-Jewish father to whom he owes gratefulness for having raised him and supported his Jewish growth.

**It is clear that there is no *halakhic* obligation to mourn for a non-Jew, at the same time certain mourning rites might be appropriate.**

R David Brofsky in his book [Hilkhot Avelut](https://korenpub.com/products/hilkhot-avelut) (p. 109) writes explicitly

> The Torah does not recognize the relationship between a person born of
> a Jewish mother and his non-Jewish father

At the same time, for converts (and it also applies in this context), he continues

> of course, a convert should treat his or her non-Jewish parents with
> appropriate respect ([SA YD 241:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.241.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) [...] as an expression go gratitude for their
> having brought him into this world. (Igrot Moshe YD 2:130)

He then goes on to discuss which practices one can voluntarily adopt in such a case and suggests reciting Kaddish (R Ovadia Yosef in Yehave Daat 6:60 concurs and adds one should sit *shiva*, R Yaakov Ariel agrees with Kaddish but suggests saying it after *Aleinu* to distinguish between him and other orphans). He mentions rending his garments as a possibility but cautions against observing laws which compromise religious observance, e.g., refraining from Torah study.

See further sources and suggested practices [here](https://www.aish.com/atr/Convert-Mourning-Kaddish-for-Non-Jewish-Parent.html), [here](https://medium.com/@rabbiyanklowitz/the-converts-dilemma-mourning-a-gentile-parent-ab73744a8d17) and [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281586/jewish/Who-Sits-Shiva-and-Mourns-for-Whom.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I know a woman who is the daughter of a Jewish woman and non-Jewish man. When her father died, she was not obligated to sit shiva, etc., but her rabbi (a well known charedi rav) did call her to express condolences. So I don't think there is a specific halachic requirement, but the child could mourn as seems appropriate.