# Learning l'iluy nishmat a non-Jew

Tags: gentiles, torah-study

Is it permissible to learn Torah - for example, Mishnayot - l'iluy nishmat a non-Jew?

Comment: Why might it not be that you think to ask?

Comment: @DoubleAA two reasons: a. Non-Jews can't learn most of Torah (only specific things) and there's also a problem of teaching non-Jews Torah, so there might be some relation to that. b. When trying to find answer online, I saw mention of an idea that I may have heard in the past, that non-Jews don't have a soul or have a different kind of soul or something like that. Maybe there's a nafka mina to that.

Comment: How is this opinion based?

Comment: @robev what do you mean?

Comment: This question has three votes to close it as opinion based. I'm expressing my bewilderment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Yaakov Hillel has a lengthy 20 page response on this in מקבציאל ל"ה where he summarizes the outcome of a ger doing things for his deceased non-Jewish parents as follows:

1 - A non-Jew has no neshama like a Jew, and therefore it makes no sense to say kaddish, learn Torah, or do any mitzva "l'iluy nishmat" a goy.

2 - One should have hakorash hatov to goy that helped them, and if they were not antagonistic to Judaism he should give tzedaka and daven that Hashem should reduce punishment for sins they may deserve.

3 - If they kept the seven mitzvos on Noach, he can add on a tefila that they should be able to enter the special Gan Eden set aside for such people.

4 - If they did not serve Avoda Zara, had good middos and surely if they were nice and helpful to Jews, one can daven that they should enter the gan eden for chasidie umos ha'olam.

[Rav Elyashiv is quoted in וישמע משה  that it is a disgrace to have a goy's name on a torah.]

[image: M,m'Kab'tziel]

Comment: If you say Liliui Nefesh instead then it's ok?

Comment: So learning isn't okay? If so, what's the difference between learning and praying & giving tzeddakah?

Comment: Rav Ovadia Yosef allowed Kaddish for a non-Jew https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3843/759

Comment: @Harel13 It doesn't say learning isn't ok. It just says it doesn't do anything special for the gentile. Learning is always a good thing.

Comment: Do gentiles not get credits for causing Jews to do good things? This author may be very kabbalistic about how 'ilui neshama' works, but he can't deny the rationalistic explanation still applies here.

Comment: @DoubleAA in other words, it's pointless to learn for the sake of a deceased non-Jew. Of course learning is always good, but for that person's sake it wouldn't have any effect?

Comment: @Harel13 No one said anything about learning "for the sake of" only learning "lilui nishmas". I know it sounds like I'm picking hairs, but that's what this answer is addressing, taking "nishmas" very literally. (Also remember, as noted above from ROY, not everyone agrees with this answer.)

Comment: @Harel13 - He writes that praying and giving Tezdaka are things that are equal to all, while Torah and Mitzvos they have no connection to.

Comment: @Harel13 - All of his conclusions are  sourced in his 20 page response.

Comment: @פריזהב oh, sorry, I missed the part about not learning Torah. Thanks.

Comment: @פריזהב Is praying and charity not included in Mitzvos? I dont understand how to determine what goes in which category. (or what 'having a connection to' means or why it affects their ability to benefit from  my doing something I'm supposed to because they caused me to)

Comment: This Shut is difficult to understand. The word Nishmat is from Tora, Nishmat Chayim, not from a kabala concept of NRNCY, the 5 nefashot.

Comment: There is a lot of Rabanim in Gemara with a name that is not jew. Onkelos, etc... and the Gemara did not change their names